# Encryption for iOS 3des not same as android and .net

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, iphone, .net

I'm trying do some encrypt something using 3des on the iOS that must match the results from java and .NET.

**Java code is :**

```
public class EncryptionHelper {

// Encrypts string and encode in Base64
public static String encryptText(String plainText,String key, String IV) throws Exception {
    // ---- Use specified 3DES key and IV from other source --------------
    byte[] plaintext = plainText.getBytes();//input
    byte[] tdesKeyData = key.getBytes();// your encryption key

    byte[] myIV = IV.getBytes();// initialization vector

    Cipher c3des = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec myKey = new SecretKeySpec(tdesKeyData, "DESede");
    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(myIV);

    c3des.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey, ivspec);
    byte[] cipherText = c3des.doFinal(plaintext);
    String encryptedString = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText,
            Base64.DEFAULT);
    // return Base64Coder.encodeString(new String(cipherText));
    return encryptedString;
}
```

}

**and iOS code for the same is :**

```
-(NSString*)new3DESwithoperand:(NSString*)plaintext encryptOrDecrypt:(CCOperation)encryptorDecrypt key:(NSString*)key initVec:(NSString*)initVec
{

NSData* data = [plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const void *vplainText = [data bytes];;
size_t plainTextBufferSize = [data length];
NSLog(@"%@, Length: %u",[data description],[data length]);

size_t bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSize3DES) & ~(kCCBlockSize3DES - 1);
NSLog(@"%zu, sizof of uint8_t: %zu",bufferPtrSize, sizeof(uint8_t));
size_t movedBytes = 0;
uint8_t *bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
NSLog(@"%zu",sizeof(bufferPtr));
memset((void*)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);
NSLog(@"%zu",sizeof(bufferPtr));

const void * vkey = [[NSData base64DataFromString:key] bytes];
const void *vinitVec = [[NSData base64DataFromString:initVec] bytes];
NSLog(@"vinitvec: %@",[[NSData base64DataFromString:initVec] description]);

CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
ccStatus = CCCrypt(encryptorDecrypt,
                   kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                   kCCOptionPKCS7Padding & kCCModeCBC,
                   vkey,
                   kCCKeySize3DES,
                   vinitVec,
                   vplainText,
                   plainTextBufferSize,
                   (void*)bufferPtr,
                   bufferPtrSize,
                   &movedBytes);

NSData* result = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void*)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
NSString* str = [NSString base64StringFromData:result length:result.length];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
return str;
```

}

This code successfully encrypts and decrypts a string. However, it does not match the results from .NET and java.
Thank you

Comment: This is called 2-key 3DES and is obsolete, not secure and should not be used in new work if at all possible.

Answer (score 8):

Have found a solution for the above problem of encryption value generated different on iOS and .NET or Java.

**Solution:**
1. In Android and .NET you have to use a key of size 16 Bytes (eg: key="1234567890123456")

In iOS you need to use a key size of 24 bytes but the generation of key makes a little difference.
Use the same key as used in Android or .NET (16 bytes) and append it with the first 8 Bytes of the same key.

key16Byte = "1234567890123456"       //Android and .NET key
key24Byte = key16Byte + "12345678"   //ios and Java key, Replicated first 8 Bytes of 16Byte key
//new24ByteKey = "123456789012345612345678"

2. Remove "& kCCModeCBC" from CCypher Mode.
3. Some values require bytes in CCCrypt function which I have changed in the below mentioned code below. like keyData, encryptData.

**Reason for different encryption generated:**
Android and .NET - It takes 16Byte key and internally replicates, and generates a 24Byte key.

Java - It throws an Exception "Invalid key length", if you provide a 16Byte key value.

iOS - It generates encryption value with 16Byte and 24Byte both values without throwing any exception, so is the reason we get a different encryption generated in case of 16Byte key.

**Java Code**

```
public class EncryptionHelper {

// Encrypts string and encode in Base64
public static String encryptText(String plainText,String key, String IV) throws Exception {
   // ---- Use specified 3DES key and IV from other source --------------
    byte[] plaintext = plainText.getBytes();//input
    byte[] tdesKeyData = key.getBytes();// your encryption key

    byte[] myIV = IV.getBytes();// initialization vector

    Cipher c3des = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec myKey = new SecretKeySpec(tdesKeyData, "DESede");
    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(myIV);

    c3des.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey, ivspec);
    byte[] cipherText = c3des.doFinal(plaintext);
    String encryptedString = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText,
            Base64.DEFAULT);
    // return Base64Coder.encodeString(new String(cipherText));
    return encryptedString;
}
```

**iOS Code:**

```
- (NSString *)encrypt:(NSString *)encryptValue key:(NSString *)key24Byte IV:(NSString *)IV{
    // first of all we need to prepare key
    if([key length] != 24)
        return @"Require 24 byte key, call function generate24ByteKeySameAsAndroidDotNet with a 16Byte key same as used in Android and .NET"; //temporary error message


    NSData *keyData = [key24Byte dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // our key is ready, let's prepare other buffers and moved bytes length
    NSData *encryptData = [encryptValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    size_t resultBufferSize = [encryptData length] + kCCBlockSize3DES;
    unsigned char resultBuffer[resultBufferSize];
    size_t moved = 0;

    // DES-CBC requires an explicit Initialization Vector (IV)
    // IV - second half of md5 key
    NSMutableData *ivData = [[IV dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]mutableCopy];
    NSMutableData *iv = [NSMutableData dataWithData:ivData];

    CCCryptorStatus cryptorStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                                            kCCOptionPKCS7Padding , [keyData bytes],
                                            kCCKeySize3DES, [iv bytes],
                                            [encryptData bytes], [encryptData length],
                                            resultBuffer, resultBufferSize, &moved);

    if (cryptorStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [[NSData dataWithBytes:resultBuffer length:moved] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

iOS

```
-(NSString *)generate24ByteKeySameAsAndroidDotNet:(NSString *)key{
    NSString *new24ByteKey = key;

    ;
    new24ByteKey = [new24ByteKey stringByAppendingString:[key substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 8)]];

    return new24ByteKey;
}
```

Comment: i have the same problem , and ask this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40887490/using-tripledes-and-md5-in-swift?noredirect=1#comment68991174_40887490 . i ll be appreciate if you help me.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jugal Desai mentioned, the key difference between iOS and Android/.Net is that the later ones automatically fill the key (with size  16 bytes) with another 8 bytes from the start of the key! You saved me :)
Here I provide the simple fix in Swift 3:

....

```
YOUR_KEY_SIZE_16 = YOUR_KEY_SIZE_16 + YOUR_KEY_SIZE_16[0...7]
```

....

Sample complete code (MD5 for key hash + ECB + PKCS7Padding) with base64 result:

```swift
func tripleDesEncrypt(keyString: String, pass: String) -> String{
    let keyData = keyString.data(using: .utf8)!

    var digestData = Data(count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))

    _ = digestData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {digestBytes in

        keyData.withUnsafeBytes {messageBytes in
            CC_MD5(messageBytes, CC_LONG(keyData.count), digestBytes)
        }
    }

    digestData = digestData + digestData[0...7]
    let data = pass.data(using: .utf8)!
    let dataNS = data as NSData

    let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int(dataNS.length) + kCCBlockSize3DES)!

    let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)
    let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
    let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
    let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

    let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
        algoritm,
        options,
        (digestData as NSData).bytes,
        keyLength,
        nil,
        dataNS.bytes,
        dataNS.length,
        cryptData.mutableBytes,
        cryptData.length,
        &numBytesEncrypted)

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        cryptData.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)

        // Not all data is a UTF-8 string so Base64 is used
        let base64cryptString = cryptData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength76Characters)
        return base64cryptString
    } else {
        print("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
    }
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How serious in decrypted?

```
- (NSString *)encrypt:(NSString *)encryptValue key:(NSString *)key24Byte IV:(NSString *)IV{
    // first of all we need to prepare key
    if([key length] != 24)
        return @"Require 24 byte key, call function generate24ByteKeySameAsAndroidDotNet with a 16Byte key same as used in Android and .NET"; //temporary error message


    NSData *keyData = [key24Byte dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // our key is ready, let's prepare other buffers and moved bytes length
    NSData *encryptData = [encryptValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    size_t resultBufferSize = [encryptData length] + kCCBlockSize3DES;
    unsigned char resultBuffer[resultBufferSize];
    size_t moved = 0;

    // DES-CBC requires an explicit Initialization Vector (IV)
    // IV - second half of md5 key
    NSMutableData *ivData = [[IV dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]mutableCopy];
    NSMutableData *iv = [NSMutableData dataWithData:ivData];

    CCCryptorStatus cryptorStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                                            kCCOptionPKCS7Padding , [keyData bytes],
                                            kCCKeySize3DES, [iv bytes],
                                            [encryptData bytes], [encryptData length],
                                            resultBuffer, resultBufferSize, &moved);

    if (cryptorStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        return [[NSData dataWithBytes:resultBuffer length:moved] base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```