# using TripleDes and MD5 in swift

Tags: ios, swift3, md5, tripledes

I have an algorithm in java code for using tripleDes and MD5. there is my java code :

```
 private String _encrypt(String message, String secretKey) throws Exception {

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(secretKey.getBytes("utf-8"));
        byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 16);

        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");


        byte[] buf = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
        byte [] base64Bytes = Base64.encodeBase64(buf);
        String base64EncryptedString = new String(base64Bytes);

        return base64EncryptedString;
    }
```

i want to using tripleDes and MD5 in swift, i'm convert this java code to swift but there is an problem in swift because in java using 16 byte and swift using 24 byte. how can solve this difference between coding in java and swift? 
there is my swift code :

```
    func myEncrypt(encryptData:String) -> String?{

            let myKeyData : NSData = ("Fanava@Wrapper!1395" as NSString).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as NSData
            let myRawData : NSData = encryptData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)! as NSData


   let mykeydatamd5 = Data(bytes: myKeyData.bytes, count: 24) // this key convert to 24 bytes but does not hash to md5 

  let mykeydatamd5 = Data(bytes: myKeyData.md5().bytes, count: 24) // this line converted key to md5(), 24byte, but it 


            let buffer_size : size_t = myRawData.length + kCCBlockSize3DES
            let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<NSData>.allocate(capacity: buffer_size)
            var num_bytes_encrypted : size_t = 0

            let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
            let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithm3DES)
            let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode | kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
            let keyLength        = size_t(kCCKeySize3DES)

            let Crypto_status: CCCryptorStatus =  CCCrypt(operation, algoritm, options, mykeydatamd5.bytes  , keyLength, nil, myRawData.bytes, myRawData.count, buffer, buffer_size, &num_bytes_encrypted)

            if UInt32(Crypto_status) == UInt32(kCCSuccess){

                let myResult: NSData = NSData(bytes: buffer, length: num_bytes_encrypted)

                free(buffer)

                return myResult.base64EncodedString(options: [])
            }else{
                free(buffer)

                return nil
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is very insecure for several reasons. 1. 3DES should not be used in new work, use AES. 2. Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption. 3. Do not use MD5 for deriving a key from a password, use PBKDF2 (Password Based Key Derivation Function 2) with a rounds value such that it takes about 100ms.

Comment: @zaph thank you for your reply, but I had to use tripleDes and MD5 because the server which we are sending data, just accept tripleDes and MD5 and i can't use anything else.

Comment: OK but it is a shame that the server implementation is not secure, it is the users that are put at risk and that is really unacceptable.

Comment: Try using JavaKey = "Fanava@Wrapper!1" and iOSKey = "Fanava@Wrapper!1Fanava@W"

Comment: Hi @ava just checking back to see if your query was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example code which can be easily modified for TrippleDES:

From the subsetted SO Documentation section

**For AES encryption in CBC mode with a random IV (Swift 3+)**

The iv is prefixed to the encrypted data

`aesCBC128Encrypt` will create a random IV and prefixed to the encrypted code.
`aesCBC128Decrypt` will use the prefixed IV during decryption.

Inputs are the data and key are Data objects. If an encoded form such as Base64 if required convert to and/or from in the calling method.

The key should be exactly 128-bits (16-bytes), 192-bits (24-bytes) or 256-bits (32-bytes) in length. If another key size is used an error will be thrown.

[PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) is set by default.

This example requires Common Crypto
It is necessary to have a bridging header to the project:
    `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>`
    Add the `Security.framework` to the project.

This is example, not production code.

```
enum AESError: Error {
    case KeyError((String, Int))
    case IVError((String, Int))
    case CryptorError((String, Int))
}

// The iv is prefixed to the encrypted data
func aesCBCEncrypt(data:Data, keyData:Data) throws -> Data {
    let keyLength = keyData.count
    let validKeyLengths = [kCCKeySizeAES128, kCCKeySizeAES192, kCCKeySizeAES256]
    if (validKeyLengths.contains(keyLength) == false) {
        throw AESError.KeyError(("Invalid key length", keyLength))
    }

    let ivSize = kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    let cryptLength = size_t(ivSize + data.count + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
    var cryptData = Data(count:cryptLength)

    let status = cryptData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {ivBytes in
        SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, kCCBlockSizeAES128, ivBytes)
    }
    if (status != 0) {
        throw AESError.IVError(("IV generation failed", Int(status)))
    }

    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0
    let options   = CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    let cryptStatus = cryptData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {cryptBytes in
        data.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
            keyData.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
                CCCrypt(CCOperation(kCCEncrypt),
                        CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES),
                        options,
                        keyBytes, keyLength,
                        cryptBytes,
                        dataBytes, data.count,
                        cryptBytes+kCCBlockSizeAES128, cryptLength,
                        &numBytesEncrypted)
            }
        }
    }

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        cryptData.count = numBytesEncrypted + ivSize
    }
    else {
        throw AESError.CryptorError(("Encryption failed", Int(cryptStatus)))
    }

    return cryptData;
}

// The iv is prefixed to the encrypted data
func aesCBCDecrypt(data:Data, keyData:Data) throws -> Data? {
    let keyLength = keyData.count
    let validKeyLengths = [kCCKeySizeAES128, kCCKeySizeAES192, kCCKeySizeAES256]
    if (validKeyLengths.contains(keyLength) == false) {
        throw AESError.KeyError(("Invalid key length", keyLength))
    }

    let ivSize = kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    let clearLength = size_t(data.count - ivSize)
    var clearData = Data(count:clearLength)

    var numBytesDecrypted :size_t = 0
    let options   = CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)

    let cryptStatus = clearData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {cryptBytes in
        data.withUnsafeBytes {dataBytes in
            keyData.withUnsafeBytes {keyBytes in
                CCCrypt(CCOperation(kCCDecrypt),
                        CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES128),
                        options,
                        keyBytes, keyLength,
                        dataBytes,
                        dataBytes+kCCBlockSizeAES128, clearLength,
                        cryptBytes, clearLength,
                        &numBytesDecrypted)
            }
        }
    }

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        clearData.count = numBytesDecrypted
    }
    else {
        throw AESError.CryptorError(("Decryption failed", Int(cryptStatus)))
    }

    return clearData;
}
```

Example usage:

```
let clearData = "clearData0123456".data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!
let keyData   = "keyData890123456".data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!
print("clearData:   \(clearData as NSData)")
print("keyData:     \(keyData as NSData)")

var cryptData :Data?
do {
    cryptData = try aesCBCEncrypt(data:clearData, keyData:keyData)
    print("cryptData:   \(cryptData! as NSData)")
}
catch (let status) {
    print("Error aesCBCEncrypt: \(status)")
}

let decryptData :Data?
do {
    let decryptData = try aesCBCDecrypt(data:cryptData!, keyData:keyData)
    print("decryptData: \(decryptData! as NSData)")
}
catch (let status) {
    print("Error aesCBCDecrypt: \(status)")
}
```

Example Output:

```
clearData:   <636c6561 72446174 61303132 33343536>
keyData:     <6b657944 61746138 39303132 33343536>
cryptData:   <92c57393 f454d959 5a4d158f 6e1cd3e7 77986ee9 b2970f49 2bafcf1a 8ee9d51a bde49c31 d7780256 71837a61 60fa4be0>
decryptData: <636c6561 72446174 61303132 33343536>
```

Notes:
One typical problem with CBC mode example code is that it leaves the creation and sharing of the random IV to the user. This example includes generation of the IV, prefixed the encrypted data and uses the prefixed IV during decryption. This frees the casual user from the details that are necessary for [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29).

For security the encrypted data also should have authentication, this example code does not provide that in order to be small and allow better interoperability for other platforms.

Also missing is key derivation of the key from a password, it is suggested that [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) be used is text passwords are used as keying material.

For robust production ready multi-platform encryption code see [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor).

If you must this functiion can be modified for 3DES.

**For PBKDF2 encryption **Password Based Key Derivation 2 (Swift 3+)**

Password Based Key Derivation can be used both for deriving an encryption key from password text and saving a password for authentication purposes.

There are several hash algorithms that can be used including SHA1, SHA256, SHA512 which are provided by this example code.

The rounds parameter is used to make the calculation slow so that an attacker will have to spend substantial time on each attempt. Typical delay values fall in the 100ms to 500ms, shorter values can be used if there is unacceptable performance.

This example requires Common Crypto
It is necessary to have a bridging header to the project:
    `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>`
    Add the `Security.framework` to the project.

Parameters:

```
password     password String  
salt         salt Data  
keyByteCount number of key bytes to generate
rounds       Iteration rounds

returns      Derived key


func pbkdf2SHA1(password: String, salt: Data, keyByteCount: Int, rounds: Int) -> Data? {
    return pbkdf2(hash:CCPBKDFAlgorithm(kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA1), password:password, salt:salt, keyByteCount:keyByteCount, rounds:rounds)
}

func pbkdf2SHA256(password: String, salt: Data, keyByteCount: Int, rounds: Int) -> Data? {
    return pbkdf2(hash:CCPBKDFAlgorithm(kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA256), password:password, salt:salt, keyByteCount:keyByteCount, rounds:rounds)
}

func pbkdf2SHA512(password: String, salt: Data, keyByteCount: Int, rounds: Int) -> Data? {
    return pbkdf2(hash:CCPBKDFAlgorithm(kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA512), password:password, salt:salt, keyByteCount:keyByteCount, rounds:rounds)
}

func pbkdf2(hash :CCPBKDFAlgorithm, password: String, salt: Data, keyByteCount: Int, rounds: Int) -> Data? {
    let passwordData = password.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!
    var derivedKeyData = Data(repeating:0, count:keyByteCount)

    let derivationStatus = derivedKeyData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {derivedKeyBytes in
        salt.withUnsafeBytes { saltBytes in

            CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(
                CCPBKDFAlgorithm(kCCPBKDF2),
                password, passwordData.count,
                saltBytes, salt.count,
                hash,
                UInt32(rounds),
                derivedKeyBytes, derivedKeyData.count)
        }
    }
    if (derivationStatus != 0) {
        print("Error: \(derivationStatus)")
        return nil;
    }

    return derivedKeyData
}
```

Example usage:

```
let password     = "password"
//let salt       = "saltData".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
let salt         = Data(bytes: [0x73, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x74, 0x44, 0x61, 0x74, 0x61])
let keyByteCount = 16
let rounds       = 100000

let derivedKey = pbkdf2SHA1(password:password, salt:salt, keyByteCount:keyByteCount, rounds:rounds)
print("derivedKey (SHA1): \(derivedKey! as NSData)")
```

Example Output:

```
derivedKey (SHA1): <6b9d4fa3 0385d128 f6d196ee 3f1d6dbf>
```